Spotfire Calculate column: Retrieve information on different columns OVER column value
I have a below data table:



ID
Changedate
PurchaseOrder
POItem
Process
Type
ReqPrice
ReqQty
ReqDate
Msg
Last_ID
Last_Price
Last_Qty
Last_ReqDate




1
3/1/2024
PO1
1
Response
Create
10
10000
3/15/2024
Accept
1
10
10000
3/15/2024


2
3/1/2024
PO1
2
Response
Create
12
2500
1/1/2025
Accept
2
12
2500
1/1/2025


3
3/1/2024
PO1
3
Response
Create
15
5000
3/1/2024
Accept
3
15
5000
3/1/2024


4
3/2/2024
PO1
1
Response
Change
10
7500
3/15/2024
Reject
1
10
10000
3/15/2024


5
3/3/2024
PO1
2
Response
Change
11
2500
7/31/2024
Accept
2
12
2500
1/1/2025


6
3/4/2024
PO1
1
Response
Change
10
11000
3/15/2024
Accept
1
10
10000
3/15/2024


7
3/5/2024
PO2
1
Response
Create
10
11000
3/15/2024
Accept
7
10
11000
3/15/2024


8
3/6/2024
PO2
1
Response
Change
10
10000
3/15/2024
Reject
7
10
11000
3/15/2024


9
3/7/2024
PO2
2
Response
Create
10
11000
3/15/2024
Reject
9
10
11000
3/15/2024



Link to Picture
I am trying to get the preceding records (Last_id, Last_Price, Las_Qty, Last_ReqDate) with the following criteria for each row's PurchaseOrder and POItem:

same PurhcaseOrder and POItem
Msg = 'Accept'

For example, for PurchaseOrder "PO1" and POItem "1", ID#4 should get ID#1's information and ID#6 should also get ID#1's information because ID#4 is 'Reject' in Msg
In addition, for the first records, I wish to show the information itself (e.g., ID#1)
I am trying to use calculated column to achieve recurring calculations but having trouble doing so.
I have concat the PurhcaseOrder and POItem as key and managed to do it per key as a calculated column, and trying to get the Last_ID in single calculated column as image above.
I sincerely appreciate your time and kind assistance!
